# Raw UDP packets using Twisted

Tags: python, udp, twisted

I'm currently using Twisted 10.1 to receive and parse UDP packets, but the standard implementation of reactor.listenUDP() only gives me access to the packet data, and I need to get the packet length from the UDP headers.

I've tried out Twisted's [pairudp.py](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/pair/examples/pairudp.py) example, but it fails with an "ImportError: No module named eunuchs.tuntap". Doing an apt-cache search for python-eunuchs comes up with nothing, and looking at Ubuntu's [package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=python-eunuchs), I can see that python-eunuchs hasn't been a part of Ubuntu since Dapper, circa 2006.

In any case, the Twisted Pair project itself is listed on it's [twistedmatrix.com](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedPair) page as unmaintained, so I would be quite hesitant to start a project using any of it's libraries.

Can anyone provide me with pointers or even a (working?) example on how I can do this using Twisted 10.1 / 10.2?

## Update

As Glyph pointed out, I'm trying to solve a problem in a complex manner that can be solved simply. Since I can get the length of the packet data using len(data), and since the length of a [UDP packet header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure) is 8 bytes, totalSizeOfUdpPacket = 8 + len(data).

****facepalm****

Comment: Why isn't len(data) adequate?

Comment: Post your self-answer below, since it's probably worth keeping this around for anyone else.

Comment: This is not a contradiction of the answer given, but I wanted to point out that I recently removed the eunuchs dependency.  Twisted Pair now has no extra dependencies (beyond those Twisted has overall).  twisted.pair.tuntap now also has pretty good test coverage and even a little bit of documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Glyph pointed out, you're trying to solve a problem in a complex manner that can be solved simply. Since you can get the length of the packet data using len(data), and since the length of a UDP packet header is 8 bytes, totalSizeOfUdpPacket = 8 + len(data).